# Keeping track of membership history of an organization once a member has been removed?

Tags: civimember, relationships

I know relationships can be disabled, but it does not seem to preserve the time they were part of the organization.

Has anyone else had a similar use case where historical data of members within an organization has to be preserved and the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You might check [`MembershipRenewal`](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.membershiprenewalcontrol) Extension.

This creates a new record when a user renew its membership, so that the older/removed/expired membership remain unaffected to let know when the user was a part of the org.